# how to go through a file with names and number scores and figure out who has first, second, third place

Tags: java, loops, io

I'm having trouble with a problem. I can't figure out why my code is working incorrectly on this problem. The problem description is this -

Ask the user for the file name of the file they want to read from.
If a file is specified that is not available, throw an exception and output "File not found." and close the program.
Otherwise, open the specified file.

Each file will have a list of users' names and their (integer) high scores for the game.
Each line will have one name and one score. This is guaranteed - you don't have to plan for anything else.
Go through all of the users and determine who won first, second, and third place.
You can assume that each file will always have at least three names/scores.

The file I'm working with is a text file called Game1Winners. This is the content of the file:

```
Mario 58

Link 576

Bowser 354

Yoshi 798

Waluigi 39

Wario 521

Toadsworth 7

Pikachu 21

Luigi 243
```

This is my code but it's working incorrectly..It's printing out first place correctly, but second and third place are out of order..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class HighScores
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What file? ");
        String filename = kb.nextLine();

        Scanner theFile = null;

        try
        {
            theFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int score = 0;
        int high_Score = 0;
        int second_Place = 0;
        int third_Place = 0;
        String name = "";
        String store1 = "";
        String store2 = "";
        String store3 = "";

        while(theFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            name = theFile.next();

            score = theFile.nextInt();

            if(score > high_Score)
            {
                high_Score = score;

                store1 = name + " with a score of " + high_Score;
            }
            if(score > second_Place && score < high_Score)
            {
                second_Place = score;

                store2 = name + " with a score of " + second_Place;
            }

            if(score > third_Place && score < second_Place)
            {
                third_Place = score;

                store3 = name + " with a score of " + third_Place;
            }

        }

            System.out.println("First place: " + store1);
            System.out.println("Second place: " + store2);
            System.out.println("Third place: " + store3);

    }
    }
```

Comment: it's working incorrectly... how do you mean?

Comment: It's giving me the first place winner, but the rest is out of order and I can't figure out why?

Comment: most likely because you don't adjust the other scores. for instance: if you have a new high score, you would overwrite the existing one, but you forget to set the current one to the second place, and the current second place to third place